# Flattening inner dimensions

Tags: julia

I have matrix (image data) of size `(209, 64, 64, 3)`. As this is image data, in order to input the matrix into a Neural Network. I need to flatten the inner 3 dimensions (2,3,4) into a single (64 x 64 x 3 = 12288) column vector. So the final matrix will be of dimensions `(12288, 209)`

How could I achieve this,

```
# I am able to flatten the entire matrix using `Iterators.flatten()` function but no clue how to flatten just the inner 3 dimensions.

a = rand(209,64,64,3)
a_flat = Iterators.flatten(a) |> collect

size(a_flat)
#Out > (2568192,)
```

Also does anyone know if the color channels in pixels must be, all red band first for all pixels of images followed by blue and green (in the format `[r; r; r; r ... b; b; b; b; ... g; g; g; g]`).

Or could it be in the form r,g,b of the first pixel, then r,g,b of the next pixel and so on (in the form `[r; b; g; r; ... g; r; b; g]`). Here I used the semicolon (;) just to show that its a column vector rather than row vector

Comment: Your problem description is a bit confusing. Do you mean that you want a (209, 12288) matrix, or do you also want to switch those dimensions? It's also unclear what you mean by "single column vector", since you will end with a matrix. For reshaping the array, check out the `reshape` function. For proper handling of rgb, check out Images.jl, where an image is a matrix of an RGB Color type.

Comment: BTW, I think you mean 'flattening the _outer_ dimensions'. The first dimension is the innermost, where the data are sequentially stored in memory, and then you move out to the other dimensions.

Comment: Hi, Your correct its the outer dimension (Apologies I was under the impression inner meant further in). And yes a column vector is perhaps an incorrect usage of words. What I was after is to un-row dimensions 2,3,4 which will result in matrix (12288, 1). And do the same for all other images which will result in (12288, 209) matrix. I've shown it in the answer below. But wondering if there was better solution.

Comment: You have to reshape the entire array, the outer dimensions aren't their own 'thing' that you can reshape to a matrix. But if you reshape the entire array, you get: `b = reshape(a, size(a, 1), :)`, which is a 209x12288 array. Then switch the dimensions with `m = permutedims(b)`. Noe you have a 12288x209 matrix.

Comment: If you are interested in proper handling of RGB images, I do suggest taking a look at the Images ecosystem: https://juliaimages.org/stable/

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with following piece of code, but there must be a better way to do this.

```
a = rand(209,64,64,3)
m = Array{Float64}(undef, (size(a)[2]*size(a)[3]*size(a)[4],size(a)[1]))

for i = 1:size(a)[1]
    m[:, i] = Iterators.flatten(a[i,:,:,:]) |> collect 
end 

size(m)
# Out > (12288, 209)
```

Comment: It looks like you want `reshape`, followed by `permutedims`.